# Wheel files and endless search loop

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I can't install a .whl file because I need pip to install it.  To install pip I need to run a .whl file.   I don't know how to install pip now because the site I use to find all the libraries (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) got rid of the exe's. I am asking if their is another way to get pip because I searched and could not find anything. When I try the bootstrap get-pip.py, I get:

Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip. No distributions at all found for pip

Comment: Python 2.7.9 and later (on the python2 series), and Python 3.4 and later include pip by default, so you may have pip already.
You may try to download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and then `python get-pip.py` to install pip

Comment: Run `python.exe pip‑6.0.6‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl/pip install pip‑6.0.6‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl`